# MYSQL Master Table / Derived Table for timeseries

Tags: mysql, group-by, time-series

I have a mysql table with timestamp(YYYY-MM-DD) and value. However the timestamps are skewed - that means they are not evenly spread. Let's say I have the following table

```
timestamp | value
2018-01-01| 10
2018-01-15| 5
2018-01-28| 0
2018-02-03| 25
2018-04-05| 12
```

I want the output as average value in the past month (or week or year.)

```
Jan | 5
Feb | 25
March| 0
April | 12
```

Basically I want to create a dummy table of months or something like that and then perform an SQL query. Is this possible ? Also depending on requirement the query might change to weekly avg value or yearly avg value also.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: You will need a master table for months. then hint: `left join` , group by, `avg()`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya They won't *need* one, but it is one idea, yes.

Comment: @Strawberry By master table, I meant that a Derived table can be used.

Comment: I tried grouping by MONTH(INTERVAL((NOW() - 12 months) to NOW())).
basically try to get the previous 12 months and group by month of the timestamp. but it didn't work. :(

Comment: @user3828311 can you create a https://www.db-fiddle.com/ ?